# Android ImageView Animation Not Showing

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview

I was having some problem when trying to animate image view in Android. Basically I got an Image view which given an ID: ivEventGuide and the codes where I tried to animate it:

```
ivEventGuide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final float growTo = 0.8f;
            final long duration = 1200;

            ScaleAnimation grow = new ScaleAnimation(1, growTo, 1, growTo,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            grow.setDuration(duration / 2);
            ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(growTo, 1, growTo,
                    1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            shrink.setDuration(duration / 2);
            shrink.setStartOffset(duration / 2);
            AnimationSet growAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
            growAndShrink.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            growAndShrink.addAnimation(grow);
            growAndShrink.addAnimation(shrink);
            ivEventGuide.startAnimation(growAndShrink);

            ivEventGuide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

So what I am trying to do is first I set the imageview to visible then it will perform the animation. After the animation is done, then I hide the image view and perform some other methods. But with these codes, the image view just disappear and not showing at all.

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to listen for the completion of the animation, before you set visibility to GONE.

```
shrink.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
          public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {}

          public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {}

          public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
               ivEventGuide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          } 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling startAnimation after setVisibility.

Comment: Its because of ivEventGuide.setVisibility(View.GONE); Do you have any ideas how to execute that line only after the animation has ended?

Comment: Try calling  ivEventGuide.setVisibility(View.GONE); first, and then ivEventGuide.startAnimation(growAndShrink);. Swap their places.

Comment: Thanks! I've got a solution